# I planned to do in the past but I didn't do

Tags: past-tense, auxiliary-verbs

> I  was going to do the work, but I didn't.

is there any model verb or any other ,I can use for same situation.

Comment: I think it depends to a degree on why you didn't do the work. For example, if something interrupted you, you could use a conditional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For actions you'd *intended* to do, but didn't get around to for whatever reason, **meant** (past tense of **mean**) will function perfectly well.

> I **meant** to do the work, but I didn't.

There are other options that will also likely work, but which one is correct would depend on context. Why *didn't* you do the work? Did something stop you? Do you wish that you'd done it?

Possibilities include:

> I **should** have done the work, but I didn't.

This conveys a sense of regret that the work was not done.

> I **needed** to do the work, but I didn't.

Same as above, but more extreme. This emphasizes the necessity that you complete the work which you haven't completed and conveys a stronger sense of regret.

> I **would** have done the work, but I didn't.

This implies that the reasons which stopped you from completing the work were beyond your control or that other matters took priority.

**Note:** Your question asked specifically for modal verbs, but I've given you any legitimate way to phrase the sentence I could think of. "Meant" and "needed" are not modal verbs, but the function they're serving here is similar.